# Automapper custom resolver throws null exception

Tags: c#, automapper, azure-mobile-services, dto

So i have a mobile Service running just fine and want to add DTOs' notation.
I use AutoMapper to map between my models and the DTOs models but the complexity of the database and the result i want forces me to use custom resolvers which in turn throws null Exceptions.

Specifically - The Mapper Initialization

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<Contact, MobileContact>()
                .ForMember(mobcont => mobcont.Favorite, map => map.ResolveUsing<ContactResolver>());//.UseValue(true));//
            cfg.CreateMap<MobileContact, Contact>();
        });
```

And my custom Resolver is

```
public class ContactResolver :  ValueResolver<Contact, bool> 
{
    protected override bool ResolveCore(Contact a)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Edited : Favorite is a bool of course

**If i dont use the custom resolver and use the .UseValue(true) it works just fine**

Though a common get request with the custom resolver as shown above throws the following exception:

```
Exception=System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at AutoMapper.QueryableExtensions.Extensions.ResolveExpression(PropertyMap propertyMap, Type currentType, Expression instanceParameter)
   at AutoMapper.QueryableExtensions.Extensions.CreateMemberBindings(IMappingEngine mappingEngine, TypePair typePair, TypeMap typeMap, Expression instanceParameter, IDictionary`2 typePairCount)
   at AutoMapper.QueryableExtensions.Extensions.CreateMapExpression(IMappingEngine mappingEngine, TypePair typePair, Expression instanceParameter, IDictionary`2 typePairCount)
   at AutoMapper.QueryableExtensions.Extensions.CreateMapExpression(IMappingEngine mappingEngine, TypePair typePair, IDictionary`2 typePairCount)
   at AutoMapper.QueryableExtensions.Extensions.<>c__DisplayClass1`2.<CreateMapExpression>b__0(TypePair tp)
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
   at AutoMapper.Internal.DictionaryFactoryOverride.ConcurrentDictionaryImpl`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
   at AutoMapper.QueryableExtensions.Extensions.CreateMapExpression[TSource,TDestination](IMappingEngine mappingEngine)
   at AutoMapper.QueryableExtensions.ProjectionExpression`1.To[TResult]()
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.Service.MappedEntityDomainManager`2.Query()
   at azmobtestService.Models.MobileContactDomainManager.Query() in c:\Users\n.atlas\Source\Repos\JPhoneBook\Service\azmobtestService\Models\MobileContactDomainManager.cs:line 104
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.Service.TableController`1.Query(), Id=75849f58-ccb0-4a6b-8a77-491f13fcb717, Category='App.Controllers.Tables'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you're doing is resolving favorite to true in all circumstances (which is not right, but that's the code you provided so I'm going with it), then your mapper could just be `.ForMember(mobcont => mobcont.Favorite, expression => expression.MapFrom(source => true));`

If you're looking for normal value resolvers, I'd go with an ITypeConverter like this:

```
public class ContactToMobileContactTypeConverter : ITypeConverter<Contact, MobileContact>
{
    public MobileContact Convert(ResolutionContext context)
    {
         var contact = (Contact)context.SourceValue;

         var mobileContact = new MobileContact();
         if(contact != null) {
             //database query
             //assign values
         }
         return mobileContact;
    }
}
```

Comment: I use AutoMapper to map between my models and the DTOs models but the complexity of the database and the result i want forces me to use custom resolvers which in turn throws null Exceptions.

Ofcourse i dont want to set it to true! 
I want to make a database request and search for a row in the Favorites table and set it to that value. As you see this search is based on user authentication(I have multiple rows of favorite per Contact per User).

Comment: I edited in some code that should work, but I believe you have to do quite a bit of work to get it working the way you want.

Comment: Changed configuration to :
cfg.CreateMap<Contact, MobileContact>().ConvertUsing( new ContactToMobileContactTypeConverter());
cfg.CreateMap<MobileContact, Contact>();

And added the code you provided. 
Debuging shows that the Convert Method is never executed! 
The new Log is :
The specified type member 'Id' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MemberAccessTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent,MemberExpression linq)... more more

Comment: Are you converting a type contact to mobile contact in your test? The code should look something like `var mobileContact = _mappingEngine.Map<MobileContact>(aContact);`

Comment: I use MappedEntityDomainManager asigned to a TableController and i simply make a get request. I think its supposed to make the conversion on the fly. but let me check

Comment: It seems your code works just fine! 
Manually mapping to Mobile Contact finally worked after some modifications, which arises me the new Question: How does MappedEntityDomainManager Works

Comment: I personally have not used the `MappedEntityDomainManager` because regular mapping has always fulfilled my needs. I'm sorry I can't help you further :(